# why index not built after successful create index in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to create an index in my postgresql database. The index command is similar to following -

```
CREATE INDEX concurrently tablename_colname_idx ON tablename USING btree (colname);
```

the command fails after few seconds. From the error logs I can see following error message immediately after the command -

```
[127966]:FATAL:  terminating connection due to administrator command
```

Comment: "None" is not something PostgreSQL would say.  That looks like a response from python.  Are you using python?  Are you committing the connection after the creation succeeds?  Please show the code that does this.

Comment: @jjanes There is no need to commit for ddl operations!

Comment: @Spikie That is not my experience with psycopg2, unless you go out of your way to turn on autocommit.

Comment: @Spikie You couldn't be more wrong. Not every database is ad limited as Oracle.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe @jjanes After I did some researches about ddl operations on postgresql, I found postgresql did support ```Transactional DDL``` when you use transaction block

Comment: @jjanes, I am using psql. just to add more information, I do not think there is any problem with syntax or environment. I am able to create other index using same setup (everything exactly same). but for this one case psql returns None and does not report any error. I understand this is very little information. Thats why I am asking for any suggestion to debug further.

Comment: It displays the word "None", or it doesn't display anything at all?  I don't see anything in the source code that would make it display "None".